# Not getting form-elements of external page in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, firefox, weblogic8.x

I am using weblogic 8.1.6. My problrm is  I have a parent page that is using Ajax to call a child page. The Child page is executed Into the Parent Page. Parent page has a form  and a javascript function to read all the  elements of the  form but the javascript  function is not able to read the elements of child page. I am using " form.elements[i].name " which is working fine in IE but not in firefox and chorme . What should i use to read the element of child page that is executed inside parenPage.

parent code

```
<form id="Tab">  
   <input type="button" onclick="alert('calling AjaX Method');" value="ADD" />  
   <div id="ChildOutputWillDisplayedHere"></div>
</form>`
```

childCode

```
<input class="FormFields" type = "text" name = "NameID" value = "">
<a href="#" onclick="callingJavscriptFunction()">click Me </a>`
```

javascript code

```
callingJavscriptFunction(){
    var form = document.forms['tab'];
    for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) 
    {
        var fieldName = form.elements[i].name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be helpfull: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms

Comment: Thanks . but i have used same code.  i have only 1 form that is in d parent page and with d FF i am not able to access d  elements of child page that is executed inside d form of d parent page. javascript code part that worked in IE but not in FF               ......................................var form = document.forms[getNetuiTagName("tabView",this)];........................... for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) 
    {
   
        var fieldName = form.elements[i].name;......................................... in case of FF fieldName is not getting elements of child page

Comment: Please add code-snippets of the form and script to your question. There won't be a reference to the element, because you're assingning it's name to `fieldName`. I can't understand, how this code would work in IE either.

Comment: parent code eg:   <form id="Tab">  
 <input type="button" onclick="alert('calling AjaX Method');"  
 value="ADD" />  
 <div id="ChildOutputWillDisplayedHere">     
           </div>
</form>                                                                                                                                  Child code  :  <input class="FormFields" type = "text" name = "NameID" value = "">
  <a href="#" onclick="callingJavscriptFunction()">click Me </a>

Comment: Again: Please add the code of the form and script to your question, not in a comment.

Comment: javascriptFunction :  callingJavscriptFunction(){
 var form = document.forms['tab'];
   for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) 
    {
        var fieldName = form.elements[i].name;
    }

}                                                                    not able to read child input elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that IE gives you all input-elements in the form, even if they didn't have `name`-attribute. Your `input` in `Tab` however lacks the `name`-attribute, which you try to read in the function. AFAIK this code will assign `undefined` to `fieldName` in IE also.

Looping like this will assign only the `name` of the last element in the `elements`-collection to your `fieldName`-variable. No problem with one `input`-element, but if there are more...